# Diferença entre o uso de const e function em componente React

Tags: react

Qual a diferença de modo geral entre funções e const dentro de componentes React?

Ex:

```
 function teste(){
    console.log('teste');
 }

 const teste = function(){
    console.log('teste');
 }

 const teste = () => {
    console.log('teste');
 }
```

Sei que as arrow functions não possuem o **this** por exemplo, mas na criação de um componente react tem alguma diferença entre usar um e outro no caso de não utilizar o **this** por exemplo?

Comment: São apenas formas diferentes de criar uma função

Comment: Nesse seu caso não há diferença nenhuma. Utilize da forma  que ficar mais confortável

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que se tratando de componentes funcionais, a única diferença seria a ausência do hoisting nas arrow functions e funções anônimas, porém quando tratamos de classes as funções são substituidas por metodos dentro da classe, precisando usar o bind no constructor sempre quando o passarmos para algum outro componente.
O this só será usado em classes, e nesse caso para se referir aos métodos da classe por exemplo:

```js
import React from 'react';

class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this);
  }

  myMethod() {
    console.log("Clicked");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={ this.myMethod }>Click-me</button>
    )
  }
}

export default MyClass;
```

Comment: Não sei se por conta das versões mais novas do react, mas nunca precisei do this.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this); para conseguir passar um método ou função para outro componente

Answer (score -1):

1. Falando especificamente de const e function, uma diferença é que quando usar const os componentes devem ser criados antes de serem usandos para evitar erro de lint.
2. Falando de classe e function sobre o this, devemos observar que o this é mutavel, veja esse exemplo para enterder o que quero dizer: https://overreacted.io/pt-br/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/406395)